# Avoiding Dupes when pushing values from form to array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having problems avoiding dupes with my code.  Here is a simplified example.  I know the problem is in the array object being a reference of the same scope variable, but what is the best way to avoid it?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item" />
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module('myApp', []).
  controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.items.push($scope.item);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8Fuk/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what your goal is.

If you want to allow for duplicate values you need to change the code a bit as each item in the ngRepeat has to have a unique id. See the `track by` section [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).

That would work like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item" />
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item.value }}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module('myApp', []).
  controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.items.push({value:$scope.item});
    }
  });
</script>
```

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Fuk/9/).

If you don't want to allow for the same values you need to search for it.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item" />
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module('myApp', []).
  controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.save = function() {
      var found = $scope.items.reduce(function(previous, i){
          if ($scope.item === i) return true;
          return previous;
        }, false);
      if (found){
        alert('duplicate value');
      }
      else{
        $scope.items.push($scope.item);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Fuk/10/).

Comment: This works for anyone looking.  It turns out in my specific case the input box is now tied to both objects in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Use [track by](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat%3adupes) syntax to fix this problem.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
   {{ item }}
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dThU/).